# How to remove an attribute with PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

The only thing I'm seeing from google searches is that

> Element.writeAttribute() - Adds, specifies or removes attributes passed as either a hash or a name/value pair.

However, the only examples I see is adding/modifying and attribute/value, not removing.

Say that I have html element

```
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" class="myclass" checked="checked" />
```

How would I remove the `checked` attribute using PrototypeJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/d9411e5/src/prototype/dom/dom.js#L2363) shows:

```
function writeAttribute(element, name, value) {
  …
  if (value === false || value === null)
    element.removeAttribute(name);
  …
}
```

So just calling it like this should do the trick:

```
$("chk").writeAttribute("checked", false);
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/VYt2d/)

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [vanilla JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.removeAttribute) and the `element.removeAttribute()` method... though it isn't Prototype